# How to manually terminate a running Service Worker

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps, web-worker

I have developed a somewhat stateful Service Worker (which is admittedly not the best practice) and I have a need to manually terminate it in order to reset it.

The need arises when I am changing the user within my client application. As such I don't close the browser tab though I do however navigate outside of the Service Worker's scope (within the same site).

- I cannot afford to wait the ~60 seconds or so before the Service Worker automatically terminates (having navigated outside of its scope or closed the client tab).
- I cannot close the client browser tab (this is not a good user experience in my scenario).
- I am not looking to uninstall/unregister the service worker.
- It seems like the `ServiceWorkerGlobalScope` does not inherit the `close()` method from `WorkerGlobalScope`.
- It seems like `navigator.serviceWorker` does not inherit `terminate()` method from WebWorker.

How can I manually stop the Service Worker from running and to clear its state?

Comment: What is state of service worker? var, cache ... ? when you change the user u need load a new service worker inemdiately?

Comment: After having changed the user I need to be able to fire up the service worker again when visiting the scope covered which could be mere seconds later dependent on behavior.  A ~60 second span (before being terminated) leaves plenty of time for the second user to encounter the same old running instance with incorrect state.
Besides internal global state the Service Worker also needs to change caches in use as well as IndexedDB instance.

Comment: A service worker only controls the scope level it is set to and subdirectories, perhaps reconsider its directory?

Comment: I guess one could have the user-id as a segment in the URL to force the use of a different SW i.e. /mywebpage/[user-id]/app/ . It's not an answer to the question but it could have been a potential way to handle the scenario described.

Answer (score 0):

you can terminate a service worker with this:

```
navigator.serviceWorker
  .getRegistration('/miSwScope')
  .then(function(registration) {
    if (registration) {
      registration.unregister();
    }
  });
```

or clear all:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then(function(regs) {
  regs.forEach(reg => {
    reg.unregister();
  });
});
```

but to clear state and init state again you need implement your own logic depending of your app.

Comment: This does not solve the issue as it permanently removes the Service Worker.
_"I am not looking to uninstall/unregister the service worker."_
If I now go offline and I try to reach the site it will no longer work as the SW does not exist.

Comment: you can register it again when you redirect back. or use a event listener to the fetch event in your service worker and when the url matches with your redirect url aply your "reset logic".

Comment: It is not possible to register it if you are offline and cannot fetch the service-worker.js file from the server.

As for reset logic: This is what I'm trying to avoid at the moment as it will involve a lot of new code and a lot of testing to clear state out properly without stopping/terminating the service-worker.